# how to use buffer to read and write java objects

Tags: java

I need to write and read objects to file.
How i can do it with use of buffer?
When i use it like that it's only write the last object to the file.

```
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(DRB );
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );

        try{
            out.writeObject(e1);
          }
          finally
          {
            buffer.flush();
            out.close();
          }
```

Comment: what is e1? you need to give us more code

Comment: Do you do this (the snippet) in a loop? I guess you are overwriting the file rather than appending to it.

Comment: You're only writing one object in the code you've shown us - and it will overwrite any previous contents in the same file. We need more context here.

Comment: Give some more code or error to describe your question well.

Comment: DRB- is the file i create.    e1- is the object i get for input.        the code is my method for writing objects to the file and i execute this method with severl objects and only the last one saves in the file

Comment: i need that the method write all the input objects to the file by thier input order

Comment: Open the file in append mode, then. Only create it if it does not exist.

Comment: ObjectInput/OutputStreams are already buffered, are you sure you need to double buffer your reads and writes?

Comment: ObjectStreams are not designed to be appended this way.  Once you close the stream you cannot change your mind and add something later. See my answer for a couple of options.

Comment: Ooops, Peter is of course totally right. Worked too much with text lately :)

Comment: the demand is each time read al the file and write it from the start with the new object. how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

To append to an ObjectOutputStream there is only two options as I see it

- read all the data into a list, add the item and write all the objects. An ObjectStream is a single continous stream. It is not like text where you can keep adding to the end.
- use your own format to write multiple independent stream to the same file.  You can write to a ByteArrayOutputStream, and use this to write the length of the stream before writing the contents.  This way you can read the individual stream back in.  I would only do this if you are confident in processing binary files.

Comment: the demand is each time read al the file and write it from the start with the new object. how do i do that?

Comment: If the file exists, read it using an ObjectInputStream and store all the objects in memory.  A simple way to do this it to save all the objects in a List and then you just need to read and write the List of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The object you used e1 must be serialized class.

That's the only criteria.

Comment: as he can see only last line been written, i think its understood that its serializable. Otherwise exception is definitely there to fill up the console. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have List of objects you want to write. Then, you can write this list.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code give below. Hope this will solve your problem:

```
package com.shineed.io;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Deserializer{

   public static void main (String args[]) {

       Deserializer deserializer = new Deserializer();

       Customer customer = deserializer.deserialzeCustomer();

       System.out.println(customer);
   }

   public Customer deserialzeCustomer(){

       Customer customer;

       try{

           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("c:\\customer.txt");
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
           customer = (Customer) ois.readObject();
           ois.close();

           return customer;

       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       } 
   } 
}
```

Also see the Customer class given below:

```
package com.shineed.io;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String adress;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }
    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

}
```